# Search_tweets() (rtweet package) does not return all expected columns

Tags: r, twitter, rtweet

I'm using the rtweet package and it's not returning the database with all columns with the search_tweets() function. The database has only 35 columns and no columns "screen_name" and "mentions_screen_name". Please how to get the rest of the columns? Below an example the columns returned.

tweets.df <- search_tweets("science")

names(tweets.df)

```
 [1] "created_at"                    "id"                           
 [3] "id_str"                        "full_text"                    
 [5] "truncated"                     "display_text_range"           
 [7] "entities"                      "metadata"                     
 [9] "source"                        "in_reply_to_status_id"        
[11] "in_reply_to_status_id_str"     "in_reply_to_user_id"          
[13] "in_reply_to_user_id_str"       "in_reply_to_screen_name"      
[15] "geo"                           "coordinates"                  
[17] "place"                         "contributors"                 
[19] "is_quote_status"               "retweet_count"                
[21] "favorite_count"                "favorited"                    
[23] "retweeted"                     "possibly_sensitive"           
[25] "lang"                          "retweeted_status"             
[27] "quoted_status_id"              "quoted_status_id_str"         
[29] "quoted_status"                 "text"                         
[31] "favorited_by"                  "display_text_width"           
[33] "quoted_status_permalink"       "query"                        
[35] "possibly_sensitive_appealable"
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have installed the development version of rtweet 0.7.0 < rtweet > 1.0.0 which is not released yet on CRAN. Could you post the `packageVersion("rtweet")` output?

The devel version of rtweet returns only the columns returned by the API but the user information is retrieval via `users_data(tweets.df)`. There you will find the id and screen name of the user who posted the tweets.
The previous `mentions_screen_name` is the `in_reply_to_screen_name` column.
Please make sure that you read the documentation of the version you are using

Answer (score 0):

Get users data of the tweets using `users_data` method

```
tweets <- search_tweets("science", n = 100)
users <- users_data(tweets)
# get screen names of users
users["screen_name"]
```